# How to parse json data using prototype.js and iterate through it?

Tags: json, prototypejs

I have json array like

```
var data = '[{ "name": "Violet", "occupation": "character" },{ "name": "orange", "occupation": "color" }]'
```

How to parse the the data and iterate through it using prototype.js?

Comment: [Searching for `prototypejs parse json`](https://.google.com/search?q=prototypejs+parse+json)  lead me to [the official Prototype.js documentation](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/String/prototype/evalJSON/). And how to iterate over arrays should be explained in every good JavaScript tutorial, for example: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `evalJSON()`

```
var data = '[{ "name": "Violet", "occupation": "character" },{ "name": "orange", "occupation": "color" }]';
data = data.evalJSON();
//for more security:
data = data.evalJSON(true); //sanitizes data before processing it
```

Then just use `for` to iterate through the array:

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{ 
    //do whatever you like with data[i];
}
```

Or use the prototypeJS `.each()` function:

```
data.each(function(el){
    //do whatever you like with el
});
```

Comment: actually you can use the `each()` method to iterate through the data http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/each/